# How to register a client name with Google?

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I have two applications which access my users' calendars via a service account. Until today everything was working fine and out of a sudden one of the app cannot get a grant token. I read that this may be due to the same service account being used simultaneously (which was the case for a year but never mind) so I decided to

- create a second service account
- and authorize it to access the calendars

I created the service account in the Google Developers Console -> API Manager -> Credentials.

The console now looks like this:

[image]

`Service account client 1` is the original service account which was working for both apps and now works for one of them only. The `ga...` account is the newly created one.

In order to get the ClientID I went (on the same page) to "Manage service accounts" and I get this:

[image]

**The newly created account does not offer the possibility to check its ClientID. Why?**

The ClientID is also available in the JSON file downloaded upon creation. I extracted it from there and tried to authorize the access in my GApps Security console:

[image]

As you can see it was refused.

**What part did I miss when creating this second account?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it:

[image]

and after checking the checkbox below both accounts look the same, the ClientID is available and it can be authorized in the GApps console.

[image]